# Android Studio Build Failed - Task :app:dexBuilderDebug FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex, android-build

I get the error message **Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited**. This is the detailed build output (which I'm only posting the beginning and the end of because it is too long)

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type com.example.currencyconversion.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig.class, /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig 2.class","sources":[{"file":"/Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig.class"}],"tool":"D8"}
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There was a failure while executing work items
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.workerExecutionException(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:264)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:246)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.doProcess(DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.kt:280)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask.doTaskAction(DexArchiveBuilderTask.kt:282)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:34)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes

Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes

Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig.class

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type com.example.currencyconversion.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig.class, /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig 2.class

Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
```

This is the summarized build output when I try to run the app:

```
Type com.example.currencyconversion.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig.class, /Users/eimanalwahhabi/Desktop/CurrencyConversion/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/currencyconversion/BuildConfig 2.class
```

This is a picture of the build output errors: [Build Output errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvzMz.png)

This is my buildConfig.class

```
package com.example.currencyconversion;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.currencyconversion";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";

    public BuildConfig() {
    }
}
```

This is Module build.gradle. You can see here that I tried to solve the problem by adding the Multidex dependency but it still didn't work.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.currencyconversion"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

This is Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that this has anything to do with it but I believe it might.  I am storing the project in the cloud.  Therefore it may appear to Android Studio that file may have multiple versions.  But the answer below of cleaning the project and rebuilding worked for me as well.  OR .. it could be this:  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by running a clean build

Comment: i have same issue but clean build and invalidate cache and restart not  resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

After a little investigation, the easiest fix is to navigate to the BuildConfig.java file and remove/trash it.  Then rebuild your project and it will be regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project then make project work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Qt 6.6.2 and it did not work with JDK-21. I had to downgrade to JDK-17, which then worked.